# Python: Matrix manipulation?

Tags: python, matrix, text-processing

I have text file with that contains 10 columns delimited by space.The column 3 has time in seconds. The column 7 and 9 contains text which are extracted and their unique values are sorted alphabetically saved in a list Np & Ns. Using the size of Np & Ns, I made a zero matrix. Now I want to check the list elements in Np with column 9. If the Np == column [9], then take time from the same row go 30s up & down and get the column [7] text values and count the no of times that each word is repeated between +30s to -30s. add the corresponding values to the matrix column. For all Np == column 9 it should add successively

Attached picture for better understanding

[image: Picture for better understanding]

I wrote few lines of code too . If any help in proceeding further will be helpful

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
fname = 'TheBigBangTheory.Season01.Episode01.speakername'
s_name  = []
p_name  = []
with open('%s.ctm'%fname, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        colum = line.split(' ')
        colum = [col.strip() for col in colum]
        nsn = colum[7]
        npn = colum[9]
        s_name.append(nsn)
        p_name.append(npn)

Np = sorted (np.unique(p_name))
Np.remove('"')
Ns = sorted (np.unique(s_name))
print(Np)
print(Ns)
A = np.zeros((len(Ns),len(Np)))
print(A)
```

Thanks in advance.